# Is it possible to shorten something like this in any way beautifully?

Tags: python, api

As a parameter, the function receives an API response reduced to Python data types. (`response.json()`)

```
def check_response(response):
    if not response['homeworks']:
        raise Exception('no homeworks')
    elif type(response) != dict:
        raise Exception("not dict")
    elif type(response['homeworks']) != list:
        raise Exception('homeworks not in list')
    elif response == {}:
        raise Exception('empty')
    else:
        return response['homeworks']
```

Comment: I don't see much repetition, each condition and exception is different. There's nothing that can be simplified.

Comment: You should use `not isinstance(variable, type)` rather than `type(variable) != type`

Comment: Barmar, what you think about it? [Can i short it?](https://i.imgur.com/irpzDtA.png)

Comment: Not really. There needs to be some code that's similar so you can combine them. Or a common pattern to different parts of the code.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-switch-statement-switch-case-example/